# Transfer Socket from one Activity to another

Tags: android, sockets, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to transfer `Socket` attribute from one `Activity` to another but i can not use `Intent.putExtra()` method.

```
socket = new Socket("10.0.0.9", port);
i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("mysocket", socket);
```

How i can transfer `Socket` from one `Activity` to another?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't 'pass a Socket' from one Activity to another, but you do have other options.

**Option 1**. Create a class with a static reference to your Socket and access it that way. In your first Activity you set the Socket, which can then be accessed statically from your second Activity.

Eg.

```
public class SocketHandler {
    private static Socket socket;

    public static synchronized Socket getSocket(){
        return socket;
    }

    public static synchronized void setSocket(Socket socket){
        SocketHandler.socket = socket;
    }
}
```

You can then access it by calling SocketHandler.setSocket(socket) or SocketHandler.getSocket() from anywhere throughout your app.

**Option 2**. Override the Application and have a global reference to the socket in there.

Eg.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private Socket socket;

    public Socket getSocket(){
        return socket;
    }

    public void setSocket(Socket socket){
        SocketHandler.socket = socket;
    }
}
```

This option will require you to point to your Application in the manifest file. In your manifest's application tag, you need to add:

```
android:name="your.package.name.MyApplication"
```

You can then access it by getting a reference to the Application in your Activity:

```
MyApplication app = (MyApplication)activity.getApplication();
Socket socket = app.getSocket();
```

Comment: You're very welcome. Don't forget to mark answers as accepted (after you've gotten it working, of course!) for others~

Comment: I haven't thought about using static... that's my distance to a senior dev