# How Do i acces or pass a custom object from/to another android activity in xamarin

Tags: android, class, sockets, xamarin, android-activity

So I have a Custom object called connector which contains a threaded socket for communicating with an Arduino without locking the UI. But I want to access this socket from multiple screens/activities.

I tried using a static class to contain the object like in this answer:

[Transfer Socket from one Activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249163/transfer-socket-from-one-activity-to-another)

But I keep getting a "name does not exist in current context" error when trying to acces it from antoher activity.

here is the code for my storage class:

```
public class ConnectorManager
{
    private static Connector connectorObject;

    public static Connector GetConnector()
    {
        return connectorObject;
    }

    public static void SetConnector(Connector connector)
    {
        connectorObject = connector;
    }
}
```

edit1:
this is how im trying to use the class:

```
ConnectorManager.SetConnector(connector);
Connector connector = ConnectorManager.GetConnector();
```

edit2:

after deleting the code file and creating a new one the problem magically fixed itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the second approach mentioned in the example you linked too. In fact I am doing this for most of my communication stuff.

```
[Application]
public class AppApplication : Application
{
    public ConnectorManager ConnectorManager { get; set; }

    public AppApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        //if you can/want create and assign your manager here
    }
}
```

In any activity you can access the application property like this:

```
((AppApplication)Application).ConnectorManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

could you please add the code sample, how did you call the static variable connectorObject in different activities?

Comment: This is not an answer. Please use comments for asking something.